# In flutter, how to position radio buttons side by side but align to the left?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I have two RadioListTiles side by side in a row, but I do not want them to take up the entirety of the row. Currently each take up half the width of the entire row and spaced apart.

I want each radio button to take up less space (or just enough) and be left-aligned, and not be so spaced apart. I have tried wrapping each in Expanded or Flexible.

[image: Spaced apart radio buttons]

```
builder: (FormFieldState<NameLineSelection> formstate) {
                                  return Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: [
                                      Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                        children: [
                                          Expanded(
                                            child: RadioListTile<NameLineSelection>(
                                              title: const Text('Single-line'),
                                              value: NameLineSelection.singleLineName,
                                              groupValue: state.nameLineSelection,
                                              onChanged: (NameLineSelection? value) {
                                                _saveForm(fieldValues);
                                                formstate.didChange(value);
                                                BlocProvider.of<VerifyMedicareBloc>(context)
                                                    .add(MedicareFormCardNameLineSelectedEvent(
                                                        _formValues, value));
                                              },
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          Expanded(
                                            child: RadioListTile<NameLineSelection>(
                                              title: const Text('Multi-line'),
                                              value: NameLineSelection.multiLineName,
                                              groupValue: state.nameLineSelection,
                                              onChanged: (NameLineSelection? value) {
                                                _saveForm(fieldValues);
                                                formstate.didChange(value);
                                                BlocProvider.of<VerifyMedicareBloc>(context)
                                                    .add(MedicareFormCardNameLineSelectedEvent(
                                                        _formValues, value));
                                              },
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      if (formstate.errorText != null ||
                                          formstate.errorText.toString() != 'null')
                                        Text(formstate.errorText.toString(),
                                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red)),
                                    ],
                                  );
                                }),
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to wrap the `RadioListTile` widget with a `ConstrainedBox` and set a `maxWidth` like so:

```
Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: const BoxConstraints(
          maxWidth: 300,
        ),
        child: RadioListTile<NameLineSelection>(
          title: const Text('Single-line'),
          value: NameLineSelection.singleLineName,
          groupValue: state.nameLineSelection,
          onChanged: (NameLineSelection? value) {
            _saveForm(fieldValues);
            formstate.didChange(value);
            BlocProvider.of<VerifyMedicareBloc>(context)
                .add(MedicareFormCardNameLineSelectedEvent(
                    _formValues, value));
          },
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: const BoxConstraints(
          maxWidth: 300,
        ),
        child: RadioListTile<NameLineSelection>(
          title: const Text('Multi-line'),
          value: NameLineSelection.multiLineName,
          groupValue: state.nameLineSelection,
          onChanged: (NameLineSelection? value) {
            _saveForm(fieldValues);
            formstate.didChange(value);
            BlocProvider.of<VerifyMedicareBloc>(context)
                .add(MedicareFormCardNameLineSelectedEvent(
                    _formValues, value));
          },
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```